# How to evaluate $\underset{x \to 1}{\lim} \frac{x^{2019} - x^{1875}}{x-1}$.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I know how to evaluate $\underset{x \to 1}{\lim} \frac{x^{2019} - 1}{x-1}$ using the definition of the derivative and the power rule. If $f(x) = x^{2019}$, then $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^{2019} - 1}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x^{2019} - 1^{2019}}{x-1} = f'(1) = 2019(1)^{2018} = 2019.$$
I assume the problem from the title is similar since the answer is $144$ according to Wolfram Alpha, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Edit: I want to know how to do this with the definition of the derivative, not L'Hospital's.

Comment: Alas, the others have beaten me to all of my good answers, but welcome, Michael. Excellent first question.

Answer (score 17):

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{x^{2019}-x^{1875}}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1} \left( x^{1875}\cdot \dfrac{x^{144}-1}{x-1}\right)$$

The product of the limits is equal to the limit of the product so long as both limits exist.

Comment: Nice, I didn't think about it :)

Answer (score 16):

Hint:
$$x^{2019}-x^{1875}=(x^{2019}-1)-(x^{1875}-1)$$

Answer (score 5):

A solution that just uses the definition of the derivative only. Specifically, consider $$f(x) = x^{a}-x^{b}.$$
Then
$$f'(1) = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^a-x^b}{x-1}.$$
Could you prove
$$f'(1) = a-b?$$

Answer (score 3):

More generally, if
$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k = 0
$
then
$\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^{b_k}}{x-1}
=\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_k
$.

Two easy proofs.

1) L'Hôpital:

$\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^{b_k}}{x-1}
=\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_k x^{b_k-1}}{1}
=\sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_k
$.

2) Elementary with positive integer exponents:

Since,
if $b$ is a positive integer,
$\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{x^b-1}{x-1}
=\lim_{x \to 1} \sum_{j=0}^{b-1} x^j
=b
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^{b_k}}{x-1}
&=\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k (x^{b_k}-1+1)}{x-1}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 1} \left(\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k (x^{b_k}-1+1)}{x-1}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x \to 1} \left(\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k (x^{b_k}-1)}{x-1}+\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k }{x-1}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k (x^{b_k}-1)}{x-1}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 1} \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{a_k (x^{b_k}-1)}{x-1}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 1} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k\dfrac{ x^{b_k}-1}{x-1}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n a_k\lim_{x \to 1}\dfrac{ x^{b_k}-1}{x-1}
\qquad\text{since all the limits exist}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n a_kb_k
\qquad\text{if all } b_k \text{ are positive integers}\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 2):

$$(x-1)\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k = x^n - 1\ \  \implies \ \ \lim_{x\to 1}\dfrac{x^n - 1}{x-1} = n$$

Apply to

$$\dfrac{x^{n+d} - x^d}{x-1}=x^d\cdot\dfrac{x^n - 1}{x-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x^a-x^b=(x^a-1)-(x^b-1)=(x-1)(x^{a-1}+x^{a-2}+\cdots1)-(x-1)(x^{b-1}+x^{b-2}+\cdots1).$$

Simplifying by $x-1$ and evaluating at $1$,

> $$a-b.$$

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: I want to know how to do this with the definition of the derivative, not L'Hospital's.

It is worth pointing out that *this distinction does not make much sense*.

When the denominator is $x-a$, what L'Hospital's rule would get you is **neither more nor less than "hey, look, this is actually the definition of a derivative!"**

In general, you want to find
$$ \lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)}{x-a}$$
for some function $g$ with $g(a)=0$. In your concrete example you have $a=1$ and $g(x)=x^{2019}-x^{1875}$.

Applying L'Hospital naively would then give you $\frac{g'(x)}{1}$. But if you want to *avoid* L'Hospital and "instead" use the definition of a derivative, you can do that too. Just note that $g(a)=0$, so
$$ \lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)}{x-a}  = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)-0}{x-a}  = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a} $$
and the right-hand side of this is exactly* the definition of $g'(a)$.

**In either case** you would now proceed to find the derivative of $x^{2019}-x^{1875}$ symbolically.

* Perhaps, depending on which textbook you get your definition from, you need to switch ariables to $h=x-a$ to get
$ \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}$ instead.

---

Small caveat: A more careful formulation of L'Hospital's rule would give you $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g'(x)}{1}$ rather than $\frac{g'(x)}{1}$ itself. But since a derivative cannot have *jump* discontinuities (due to Darboux's theorem), if this limit and $g'(a)$ both exist, they must be equal. So this version of L'Hospital gives you *less than* "hey look, this is actually the definition of a derivative", if the derivative of $g$ happens to be discontinuous at $a$.